# Calculating the variance for an average predicted probability

Tags: probability, prediction

I am trying to calculate the variance for an average predicted probability. I am using PROC GLIMMIX in SAS to generate a large number of predicted probabilities from a logisitic regression, and each predicted probability contains an associated standard error with it.

What would be my variance associated with this average predicted probability? I know that I have two sources of variance - the first is with generating the predicted probability estimate, and the second is the variance between calculating the average over all of the probabilities. I'm not sure how I should combine the two variances to arrive at a final variance for my average predicted probability.

If someone has an answer or can point me towards a paper on the topic, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!